# update-manager and apt-get are broken

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, update-manager

I'm searching everywhere but can't find a solution.

If I run `update-manager`, the **Software Updater** starts loading but then I get a **Crash Report**. Parts of the Traceback follows:

```
[...]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 67, in update
    _("Checking for updates…"), False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 159, in _show_transaction
    yield trans.run()
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/core.py", line 913, in _run
    yield self._check_auth()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/core.py", line 965, in _check_auth
    authorized = yield self._check_alternative_auth()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 477, in _inline_callbacks
    result = gen.throw(result.type(result.value).with_traceback(result.traceback))
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'action_id'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 390, in _next
    self.result = callback(self.result, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 535, in gotResult
    _inline_callbacks(res, gen, deferred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 525, in _inline_callbacks
    deferred.errback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 352, in errback
    self._next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 408, in _next
    self.result.traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 98, in apport_excepthook
    pr['_PythonExceptionQualifier'] = name
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 652, in __setitem__
    raise TypeError("value for key %s must be a string, CompressedValue, or a file reference" % k)
TypeError: value for key _PythonExceptionQualifier must be a string, CompressedValue, or a file reference
```

Now, if I try `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following:

```
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.168.4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 24, in <module>
    import debian.deb822
ImportError: No module named 'debian'
dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
 update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 3.168.4); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-manager:
 update-manager depends on update-notifier; however:
  Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-manager (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on update-manager; however:
  Package update-manager is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 update-notifier
 update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I do also get the same output if I try `sudo apt-get autoremove`. I'm using **Ubuntu 16.04** (4.8.0-49-generic).

I've searched for answers everywhere but nothing could fix my problem.

Comment: What have you tried **exactly**?  "Searched everywhere" is not passing here. Update your question with what you've tried and we'd be happy to help you

Comment: I really don't know what to do/say. I've tried removing `update-manager` and installing it back again but the error persists. I've tried reinstalling `python-debian` but I get the same output I provided while trying to `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: And what I mean by "searched everywhere" is that I didn't find anyone with the same error output I'm getting.

Comment: Any luck with that? I have the same problem with ubuntu 17.10

Comment: No, sorry. I ended up formatting it

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on 16.10, upgrade to 17.04 didn't help. I'm pretty sure the problem started because of python3 packages conflict, looking at the trace of the exception it seemed like it was using packages from `/usr/lib/python3` (apt managed) and from `/usr/local/lib/python3.5` (pip managed). I removed all my pip installed packages, I reinstalled update-manager/python3-aptdaemon/etc but that didn't work... After some additional attempts at removing and purging everything and then reinstalling, it seems that update-manager is working when using `synaptic` backend and not `aptdaemon`. So far so good. Unfortunately I can't really offer any steps to reproduce or solve this..